# to.Radian method cause my app to crash .. I don't know why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, math

I have a very strange problem ... I'm working on an app that deals with math... part of my app is that the user will enter an angle in degrees .. so the app will calculate sin of this angle and preform some equation ... the problem is when i use to.Radian() method to convert angle in degrees that the user entered my app installed properly on my android but when i clicked on the button that responsible for calculation my app crushes ... when i remove to.Radian method my app works fine but surly it gives a wrong results ...
 Here is my java code :

```
EditText faiEditText = findViewById(R.id.fai);
double fai = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(faiEditText.getText()));
double sinFai = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(fai));
double K = (1 - sinFai) / (1 + sinFai);
```

Here is my crash Log:

```
11-29 05:01:29.823 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147283223 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:01:30.080 5880-5880/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 0
11-29 05:01:30.089 5880-5880/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
11-29 05:01:50.991 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1521 [2018-11-29 05:01:50.991]
11-29 05:02:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147313400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:02:18.742 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147313400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:02:18.743 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147313400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:02:20.994 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1522 [2018-11-29 05:02:20.994]
11-29 05:02:51.002 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1523 [2018-11-29 05:02:51.001]
11-29 05:03:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147373400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:03:18.840 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147373400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:03:18.841 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147373400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:03:21.009 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1524 [2018-11-29 05:03:21.009]
11-29 05:03:51.012 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1525 [2018-11-29 05:03:51.012]
11-29 05:04:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147433400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:04:18.975 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147433400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147433400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:04:21.016 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1526 [2018-11-29 05:04:21.015]
11-29 05:04:51.019 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1527 [2018-11-29 05:04:51.019]
11-29 05:05:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147493400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:05:19.089 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147493400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=147493400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:05:21.026 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1528 [2018-11-29 05:05:21.026]
11-29 05:05:31.051 2982-3092/? E/TLC_TIMA_PKM_initialize: tima_pkm : ro.ddr_start_type does not exist
11-29 05:05:51.033 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1529 [2018-11-29 05:05:51.033]
11-29 05:06:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148723400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:06:19.207 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148723400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148723400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:06:21.038 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1530 [2018-11-29 05:06:21.037]
11-29 05:06:51.046 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1531 [2018-11-29 05:06:51.045]
11-29 05:07:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148783400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:07:19.307 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148783400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:07:19.308 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148783400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:07:21.053 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1532 [2018-11-29 05:07:21.053]
11-29 05:07:51.057 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1533 [2018-11-29 05:07:51.056]
11-29 05:08:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148843400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:08:19.414 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148843400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148843400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:08:21.060 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1534 [2018-11-29 05:08:21.060]
11-29 05:08:43.581 4386-18445/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
11-29 05:08:51.065 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1535 [2018-11-29 05:08:51.065]
11-29 05:09:21.070 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1536 [2018-11-29 05:09:21.070]
11-29 05:09:35.074 2982-4292/? E/SensorManager: sensor or listener is null
11-29 05:09:51.078 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1537 [2018-11-29 05:09:51.077]
11-29 05:10:00.002 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148908711 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:10:00.002 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148908711 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:10:21.084 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1538 [2018-11-29 05:10:21.083]
11-29 05:10:31.044 2982-3092/? E/TLC_TIMA_PKM_initialize: tima_pkm : ro.ddr_start_type does not exist
11-29 05:10:35.339 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=148998739 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:10:51.091 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1539 [2018-11-29 05:10:51.091]
11-29 05:10:57.061 446-446/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:10:57.063 446-446/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:10:58.343 467-467/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:10:58.344 467-467/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:11:08.343 495-495/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:11:08.344 495-495/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:11:18.361 512-512/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:11:18.362 512-512/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:11:21.096 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1540 [2018-11-29 05:11:21.095]
11-29 05:11:51.100 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1541 [2018-11-29 05:11:51.100]
11-29 05:12:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149083400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:12:15.646 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149083400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:12:21.105 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1542 [2018-11-29 05:12:21.105]
11-29 05:12:51.109 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1543 [2018-11-29 05:12:51.109]
11-29 05:13:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149143400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:13:17.893 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149143400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:13:17.894 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149143400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:13:21.117 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1544 [2018-11-29 05:13:21.116]
11-29 05:13:51.120 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1545 [2018-11-29 05:13:51.120]
11-29 05:14:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149203400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:14:17.893 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149203400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149203400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:14:21.127 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1546 [2018-11-29 05:14:21.127]
11-29 05:14:51.132 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1547 [2018-11-29 05:14:51.131]
11-29 05:15:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149263400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:15:17.966 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149263400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149263400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:15:21.135 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1548 [2018-11-29 05:15:21.135]
11-29 05:15:31.064 2982-3092/? E/TLC_TIMA_PKM_initialize: tima_pkm : ro.ddr_start_type does not exist
11-29 05:15:51.138 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1549 [2018-11-29 05:15:51.138]
11-29 05:16:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149323400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:16:21.144 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1550 [2018-11-29 05:16:21.144]
11-29 05:16:30.074 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149353474 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:16:30.130 2982-3007/? E/zygote: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 10043 pid 32184: No such file or directory
11-29 05:16:30.133 591-591/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:16:30.134 591-591/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:16:30.134 591-591/? E/Zygote: isSdpEnabledProcess - SDP enabled
11-29 05:16:30.136 591-591/? E/Zygote: isSdpEnabledProcess - SDP enabled
11-29 05:16:30.138 5880-5880/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 0
11-29 05:16:30.153 5880-5880/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
11-29 05:16:51.151 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1551 [2018-11-29 05:16:51.151]
11-29 05:17:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149383400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:17:21.157 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1552 [2018-11-29 05:17:21.157]
11-29 05:17:51.161 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1553 [2018-11-29 05:17:51.161]
11-29 05:18:00.517 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149383400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:18:00.518 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149383400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149383400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:18:00.562 629-629/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:18:00.563 629-629/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:18:00.687 646-646/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:18:00.687 646-646/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:18:21.165 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1554 [2018-11-29 05:18:21.165]
11-29 05:18:51.147 31460-31460/? E/adbd: recv: OPEN 00000312 00000000 0022:73 68 65 6C 6C 3A 6C 73 20 2F 73 79 73 74 65 6D 2F 62 69 6E 2F 73 63 72 65 65 6E 72 65 63 6F 72 64 00 
11-29 05:18:51.169 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1555 [2018-11-29 05:18:51.168]
11-29 05:19:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149503400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:19:00.657 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149503400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149503400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:19:09.009 5880-18693/? E/SPPClientService: [b] __PingReply__
11-29 05:19:21.176 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1556 [2018-11-29 05:19:21.176]
11-29 05:19:26.068 2982-3008/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
11-29 05:19:26.088 2982-3008/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
11-29 05:19:51.179 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1557 [2018-11-29 05:19:51.179]
11-29 05:20:21.183 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1558 [2018-11-29 05:20:21.183]
11-29 05:20:31.048 2982-3092/? E/TLC_TIMA_PKM_initialize: tima_pkm : ro.ddr_start_type does not exist
11-29 05:20:51.189 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1559 [2018-11-29 05:20:51.189]
11-29 05:21:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149620797 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:21:17.950 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149620797 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:21:17.951 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149620797 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:21:21.193 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1560 [2018-11-29 05:21:21.193]
11-29 05:21:51.197 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1561 [2018-11-29 05:21:51.197]
11-29 05:22:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149683400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:22:18.050 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149683400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:22:18.051 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149683400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:22:21.202 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1562 [2018-11-29 05:22:21.202]
11-29 05:22:51.205 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1563 [2018-11-29 05:22:51.205]
11-29 05:23:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149743400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:23:18.158 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149743400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149743400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:23:21.212 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1564 [2018-11-29 05:23:21.212]
11-29 05:23:51.215 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1565 [2018-11-29 05:23:51.215]
11-29 05:24:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149803400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:24:18.251 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149803400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149803400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:24:21.218 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1566 [2018-11-29 05:24:21.218]
11-29 05:24:51.221 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1567 [2018-11-29 05:24:51.221]
11-29 05:25:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149863400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:25:18.366 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149863400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149863400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:25:21.228 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1568 [2018-11-29 05:25:21.228]
11-29 05:25:31.045 2982-3092/? E/TLC_TIMA_PKM_initialize: tima_pkm : ro.ddr_start_type does not exist
11-29 05:25:51.232 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1569 [2018-11-29 05:25:51.232]
11-29 05:26:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149923400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:26:18.456 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149923400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149923400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:26:21.235 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1570 [2018-11-29 05:26:21.235]
11-29 05:26:51.238 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1571 [2018-11-29 05:26:51.238]
11-29 05:27:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149983400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:27:18.535 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149983400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=149983400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:27:21.241 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1572 [2018-11-29 05:27:21.241]
11-29 05:27:43.788 4386-18445/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
11-29 05:27:51.245 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1573 [2018-11-29 05:27:51.244]
11-29 05:28:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150043400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:28:18.658 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150043400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:28:18.658 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150043400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:28:21.251 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1574 [2018-11-29 05:28:21.251]
11-29 05:28:51.255 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1575 [2018-11-29 05:28:51.255]
11-29 05:29:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150103400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:29:21.259 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1576 [2018-11-29 05:29:21.259]
11-29 05:29:45.310 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150103400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150103400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:29:51.264 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1577 [2018-11-29 05:29:51.264]
11-29 05:30:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=150163400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:30:21.267 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1578 [2018-11-29 05:30:21.267]
11-29 05:30:31.047 2982-3092/? E/TLC_TIMA_PKM_initialize: tima_pkm : ro.ddr_start_type does not exist
11-29 05:30:45.454 2982-3008/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
11-29 05:30:45.493 2982-3008/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
11-29 05:30:51.271 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1579 [2018-11-29 05:30:51.271]
11-29 05:31:21.274 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1580 [2018-11-29 05:31:21.274]
11-29 05:31:30.121 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=154273400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:31:30.353 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=154273400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:31:30.447 5880-5880/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] reqType : 0
11-29 05:31:30.454 5880-5880/? E/SPPClientService: [[PushClientService]] F:false, D:false, E:false, T:false, S:true, R:false
11-29 05:31:51.277 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1581 [2018-11-29 05:31:51.277]
11-29 05:32:21.281 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1582 [2018-11-29 05:32:21.281]
11-29 05:32:51.284 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1583 [2018-11-29 05:32:51.284]
11-29 05:33:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=154393400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:33:00.078 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=154393400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
    Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=154393400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
11-29 05:33:00.123 843-843/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:33:00.124 843-843/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
11-29 05:33:00.125 843-843/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:33:00.342 2684-2684/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1543462380.331:2110): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=843 comm="facebook.katana" name="vmstat" dev="proc" ino=4026534951 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G610F_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
    type=1300 audit(1543462380.331:2110): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=dbc4a550 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2697 pid=843 auid=4294967295 uid=10084 gid=10084 euid=10084 suid=10084 fsuid=10084 egid=10084 sgid=10084 fsgid=10084 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="facebook.katana" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
    type=1327 audit(1543462380.331:2110): proctitle="com.facebook.katana"
11-29 05:33:00.352 2684-2684/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1543462380.341:2111): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=843 comm="facebook.katana" name="zoneinfo" dev="proc" ino=4026534952 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_zoneinfo:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G610F_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
    type=1300 audit(1543462380.341:2111): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=dbc4a5d0 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2697 pid=843 auid=4294967295 uid=10084 gid=10084 euid=10084 suid=10084 fsuid=10084 egid=10084 sgid=10084 fsgid=10084 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="facebook.katana" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
    type=1327 audit(1543462380.341:2111): proctitle="com.facebook.katana"
11-29 05:33:00.368 843-843/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.katana
11-29 05:33:01.008 843-932/? E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp: Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
11-29 05:33:01.619 2684-2684/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1543462381.601:2112): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=922 comm="Bg_Shared2" name="boot_id" dev="proc" ino=1448833 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G610F_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
    type=1300 audit(1543462381.601:2112): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=c06bc4e0 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2697 pid=922 auid=4294967295 uid=10084 gid=10084 euid=10084 suid=10084 fsuid=10084 egid=10084 sgid=10084 fsgid=10084 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="Bg_Shared2" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
    type=1327 audit(1543462381.601:2112): proctitle="com.facebook.katana"
11-29 05:33:01.620 843-922/? E/fb4a.BootIdReader: Error reading boot_id from procfs
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
        at X.28v.D(:430778)
        at X.MRS.<init>(:3134313)
        at X.MRS.B(:3134304)
        at X.Nax.B(:3287052)
        at X.0Hd.B(Unknown Source:76)
        at X.0IO.F(:47892)
        at X.0IO.D(:47907)
        at X.466.B(:790943)
        at X.4TB.init(:841851)
        at X.3FA.runNextINeedInit(:630625)
        at X.3FU.run(:630814)
        at X.0NY.run(:163021)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at X.0Od.run(:54737)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at X.0LB.run(:50727)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at X.0Og.run(:54744)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
11-29 05:33:01.648 4039-4064/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location remove af8a911 from com.facebook.katana
11-29 05:33:01.650 4039-4064/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location remove 84fa877 from com.facebook.katana
11-29 05:33:01.652 4039-4064/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [LocationManagerService] Location remove 12dc54d from com.facebook.katana
11-29 05:33:01.654 4039-4064/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [FusedLocationApi] Location remove 8307102 from com.facebook.katana
11-29 05:33:01.659 4039-4064/? E/RequestManager_FLP: [FusedLocationApi] Location remove 89aea13 from com.facebook.katana
11-29 05:33:01.896 976-976/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:33:01.897 976-976/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:33:02.041 2684-2684/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1543462382.031:2113): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=976 comm="m.facebook.orca" name="vmstat" dev="proc" ino=4026534951 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G610F_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
    type=1300 audit(1543462382.031:2113): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=dbc494c0 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2697 pid=976 auid=4294967295 uid=10167 gid=10167 euid=10167 suid=10167 fsuid=10167 egid=10167 sgid=10167 fsgid=10167 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="m.facebook.orca" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
    type=1327 audit(1543462382.031:2113): proctitle="com.facebook.orca"
11-29 05:33:02.066 2684-2684/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1543462382.051:2114): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=996 comm="EnsureDelegate" name="zoneinfo" dev="proc" ino=4026534952 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_zoneinfo:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G610F_8.1.0_0007 audit_filtered
    type=1300 audit(1543462382.051:2114): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=8 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=dd7038f0 a2=20000 a3=0 items=0 ppid=2697 pid=996 auid=4294967295 uid=10167 gid=10167 euid=10167 suid=10167 fsuid=10167 egid=10167 sgid=10167 fsgid=10167 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="EnsureDelegate" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 key=(null)
    type=1327 audit(1543462382.051:2114): proctitle="com.facebook.orca"
11-29 05:33:02.086 976-996/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.facebook.orca
11-29 05:33:02.577 1042-1042/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:33:02.577 1042-1042/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:33:07.233 976-1083/? E/CompactDiskManagerImpl.cpp: Failed to remove new folder structure directories: No such file or directory
11-29 05:33:07.481 976-1089/? E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libreliability.so
11-29 05:33:07.502 22774-22785/? E/fbservices:ak: aidlBundleKey: BLOCKED_COUNTRIES_HN_TIMESTAMP not exist in FbnsAIDLConstants
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.facebook.rti.b.a.h.BLOCKED_COUNTRIES_HN_TIMESTAMP
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:257)
        at com.facebook.rti.b.b.ak.b(SharedPreferencesBasedStateHelper.java:55)
        at com.facebook.rti.b.b.w.b(FbnsService.java:187)
        at com.facebook.i.a.a.f.onTransact(IFbnsAIDLService.java:80)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:705)
11-29 05:33:17.187 1110-1110/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
11-29 05:33:17.188 1110-1110/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
11-29 05:33:21.287 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1584 [2018-11-29 05:33:21.287]
11-29 05:33:51.291 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1585 [2018-11-29 05:33:51.291]
11-29 05:34:21.296 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1586 [2018-11-29 05:34:21.296]
11-29 05:34:51.299 2982-4003/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1587 [2018-11-29 05:34:51.299]
11-29 05:35:00.000 2982-3082/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=154513400 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
```

Comment: what value in `fai` hold? what is the exception, the error log? put more information please, thanks.

Comment: usually user will put an angle between 30 : 35 degrees .. and there is no error log ... could you help me please?

Comment: Where is your crash log?

Comment: I'm Sorry but I'm new to stack overflow and Android I don't know how to post my crash log ?!

Comment: @Assem Abed Copy your crash log into the question, I will edit it for you.

Comment: i have added my crash log to the ques

Answer (score 0):

I Tried your code and it works fine until you pass wrong data, it's much better to check the data coming from the editText or better if it will be a range of values to do it in a dropdown menu or list, so it may be because sometimes keyboard add space after you typed,  you can use toString() with trim() and surround with Try and Catch the exception.

```
      try {
                       double fai = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(faiEditText.getText().toString().trim()));
                       double sinFai = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(fai));
                       double K = (1 - sinFai) / (1 + sinFai);
                       Log.e("sinFai", K + "");
                   }catch (Exception e){
                       //better to use the right Exception for Math or Radians
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
```

Comment: i believe the problem is more mathematically because when i remove to.Radian method and enter the angle in radian directly the app also crashes ..

Comment: I put 12 despite taking this value you got from the editText and i got a result of0.6557501804175725 so actually  you should make the edittext not accepting any values or use this kind of try and catch so you can perform different scenarios.

Comment: actually sin(12 degrees) = .2079 ... so this .65575 is wrong result.

Comment: Actually K is 0.6557 and i tried with my calculator, and  toRadians() is done in the line without problem as well.